# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de la AppBar en Android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy comenzando a crear apps en Android Studio, pero no sé cómo cambiar el color de la barrita que sale arriba de la aplicación con el nombre.

Comment: Si estas comenzando a crear apps, te recomiendo leer lo más que puedes en la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html). Mucho ya esta traducido a español, aun que no todo (especialmente en temas avanzados)

Comment: Stefan porque cambiaste el titulo?  "Como cambiar el color de un RelativeLayout en Android Studio"... ahora lo cambiaste a AppBar .

Answer (score 3):

En el layout de tu `Activity` debes tener un elemento `AppBarLayout` que debería tener un parametro

```
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

el valor del parametro `android:theme` apunta a un elemento en `styles.xml`, en que tu puedes modificar parámetros del tema que usas.

En este elemento puedes agregar valores que quieres usar en vez del tema que eligiste cuando Android Studio te generó la `Activity`.

Alternativamente puedes en el elemento de tu `AppBar` (o `ToolBar`) directamente agregar un parametro con el color de fondo:

(remplaza colorPrimary por un color de tu gusto que defines en colors.xml)

```
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

La documentación oficial ya esta parcialmente traducido, lo encuentras [aquí](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html)

Comment: pero eso por ejemplo donde escribo el codigo que me dieron ustedes chicos en el text del activity main o dentro del main activity ?? sorry si la pregunta es muy estupida pero llevo poco en esto :S

Comment: Tienes que ponerlo en res/layout/...xml. No sé como se llama tu archivo de layout, porque no compartiste tu código.

Answer (score 3):

Para cambiar el color de un RelativeLayout (o cualquier otro layout) se tiene la propiedad `android:background` a la cual puedes definir un color:

```
android:background="#FF0000"
```

O programaticamente de esta forma:

```
//obtienes la referencia del Layout.
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
//aplicas color.
rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

En cuanto a la pregunta:

> como cambiar el color de la barrita que sale arriba de la aplicación
>   con el nombre.

Imagino te refieres al Toolbar, para realizar esto se usa tambien la propiedad:

```
android:background="#00FF00"
```

O programaticamente

```
//obtienes la referencia del Layout.
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_id);
//aplica color
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
```

Comment: pero eso por ejemplo donde escribo el codigo que me dieron ustedes chicos en el text del activity main o dentro del main activity ?? sorry si la pregunta es muy estupida pero llevo poco en esto :S

Comment: Hola Pablo, no te preocupes, como vas a buscar la referencia de la toolbar para cambiar el color, debe ser dentro de la Activity que carga el Layout que contiene el Toolbar o RelativeLayout. Prueba y comenta resultados.

Comment: Perfecto Ahi me funciono Muchas Gracias !!

Answer (score 0):

**Para Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch**

En la estructura de la app tienes dos archivos en los que indicar los colores:

> res/values/colors.xml

y

> res/values/themes.xml

(o res/values/themes/themes.xml si tienes más de un archivo themes.xml).

Si abres el primero (colors.xml) verás que se declaran unos nombres para los colores y se les asigna su valor.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="green_500">#4CAF50</color>
    <color name="green_700">#388E3C</color>
    <color name="Grey_500">#9E9E9E</color>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

En este archivo puedes colocar los colores que quieras usar y darles el nombre que quieras, aunque lo normal es que le des el nombre de la paleta y su número.
Desde aquí puede obtener la [paleta de colores](https://m2.material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#tools-for-picking-colors).

Una vez que hayas decidido los colores que vas a usar, debes ir a themes.xml y simplemente asignar los colores que acabas de declarar.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.ListaDeLaCompra" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/green_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

StatusBar usa primaryColor y ToolBar primaryColorVariant... es la forma más sencilla.
Ahora ya solo queda probar :-)